# How to show progress bar in PHP where i have to upload the file size of of 100MB? without APC

Tags: php, file-upload, progress-bar

How to show progress bar in PHP where i have to upload the file size of of 100MB? I cannot have APC installed. I am allowed to do so..
Help me out to get it done...

**P.S > I DO NOT HAVE DEDICATED SERVER HENCE CANNOT USE APC**

We have PHP 5.2+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the most suitable one for is [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
its simple & powerful jquery plugin and it can support queuing ,

i had test it before writing this answer with out APC

it had successfully upload 500 MB , its very handy tool

Answer (score 2):

for me the best choice is SWFupload...

check this demo: http://demo.swfupload.org/v250beta3/formsdemo/index.php
just fill the form attach a file and click send... you will see how progress bar are approaching.

you don't need any server side scripts, besides the one to handle incoming file.

Comment: Grt!! it works.. But again Y should User have to mingle into extra plugin dowmnload for flash player version.. i liked it.. and solves my almost requirement, but i dont want user to get display for downloading Flash 9+

Answer (score 2):

The best approach for uploading large files that I've seen yet is to use [PLUpload](http://www.plupload.com/).  It supports file chunnking (using Flash, Gears, Silverlight or Browser Plus) which will also allow you to keep your PHP file upload limits set lower.

> Plupload v1.2.3
>
> Allows you to upload files using HTML5 Gears, Silverlight, Flash, BrowserPlus or normal forms, providing some unique features such as upload progress, image resizing and chunked uploads.

Comment: Cant I have single file upload with this plupload?

Comment: i found single file upload in it, but for that I dont have the Progress bar in it... How to get that thing done?

Answer (score 0):

APC is really the best (read: only) choice you're going to get without recompiling PHP and using [unsupported third-party patches](http://bluga.net/projects/uploadProgressMeter/).

Have you considered using a client-side plugin to perform the upload status information?  There's [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), for example, which will pick from a variety of plugins that the user may have.

Why are you "not allowed" APC?

Comment: Because we do not have Dedicated server

Comment: Have you asked your web hosting provider about installing APC?  Unless they're a know-nothing reseller, they should seriously consider installing APC for the bytecode caching alone...

Comment: yes I did, they denied to provide it, as we have the shared server.

Comment: Consider finding another host, or switching to a Virtual Private Server.  VPSes are extremely affordable.  At the minimum, I would suggest switching hosts.  There are very few downsides to installing APC, and if they are unable to for technical reasons, you're in deep trouble anyway...

Comment: -ve not possible to switch the servers... project is already live.. and with heavy users 24x7.. cannot do switch.. need to give this functionality with present scenarios only